# Viber cannot see my photos

Tags: photos, gallery, viber-messenger

I have a Lenovo k6 with Android 7.0. It doesn't have any native gallery app but it had Google photos preinstalled instead. Every photo I take is saved in /DCIM/Camera folder.

There is a problem though. When I press the gallery button in Viber in order to send a photo I have taken, it tells me that there are no photos/videos.

If I go to Google Photos or in file manager, the photos are there.

I also had the same problem with multiple gallery apps (they couldn't find my photos as well). After I uninstalled and reinstalled QuickPick it found them for some reason.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Steps I have already tried:

- Connect the phone to my PC (make it show hidden files) and search for .nomedia files. Nothing was found.
- Deleted cache and also deleted Viber's cache.